# How to create sitemap.xml for huge data?

Tags: php, seo, sitemap

I have 1 site. 
There are more than 1 million links.

I want create a sitemap.xml, and I know, I must create sitemap_index and etc.

Do I have to add all 1 million links to my sitemap **or** should I only add new links to my sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

All link should be in there... in different sitemaps, with a sitemap index :) they should also be available in a compressed format.

Comment: how should the index work? and what is the advised compressed format? how does google know where they are?

Comment: GZIP should be used. Google knows where it is by telling Google Search Console or by adding it to robots.txt. More about sitemap indexing can be found here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en